# Unique true/false loss for every sample

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

For a binary prediction problem, if the true label is 0, the gain for right predict is T_0, the loss for wrong pre is F_0. The same for 1, T_1, F_1.

Every sample has its unique T_0, T_1, F_0, F_1. I think I need to change eval metric, but I do not know how to do it. Because most of customized eval metric only input (pred, true label), do you know how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: For example, football gambling. I pay 1 dollor for gambling. If my prediction is wrong, then I will lose 1 dollor. So F_0, F_1 equal to 1. On the other hand, if my predction is right, and team 0 win, I will get extra T_0. The same for right prediction of team 1, I will get extra T_1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one work around would be to simply append the four values `T_0,T_1,F_0,F_1` to the ground truth itself. Since the evaluation metric would only be used once, i.e. while training the classifier, your goal can be accompalished.

Suppose you somehow change your true labels from

```
[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

to this:

```
[ [1,[T_0, F_0, T_1, F_1]],
  [0,[T_0, F_0, T_1, F_1]],
  [1,[T_0, F_0, T_1, F_1]],
  [1,[T_0, F_0, T_1, F_1]],
  [0,[T_0, F_0, T_1, F_1]],
  [0,[T_0, F_0, T_1, F_1]] ]
```

i.e. each ground truth value is accompanied by an array consisting of `T_0,T_1,F_0,F_1` for that corresponding sample.

Now you can define your metric like this:

```
def my_metric(y_pred,y_true):
    tot_sum = 0.0
    for idx in range(0,len(y_pred):
        if y_true[idx][0]==0:
            if y_pred[idx]==0:
                total_sum+=y_pred[idx][1][0]   #Add gain for T_0
            else:
                total_sum-=y_pred[idx][1][1]   #Subtract loss for F_0
        else:
            if y_pred[idx]==1:
                total_sum+=y_pred[idx][1][2]   #Add gain for T_1
            else:
                total_sum-=y_pred[idx][1][3]   #Subtract loss for F_1
return total_sum
```

I think there might be an efficient way to do this using `numpy` as well, I will update the answer if I find something. However, this should work fine as long as to append the values to the ground truth correctly.

Comment: sorry, the scikit-learn does not allow multiple columns label. (ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous-multioutput'). This is the same for XGboost(ValueError: DataFrame for label cannot have multiple columns).

Comment: You can try using a global array or dataframe of the additional values ?